# how can i lock the row of a table?

Tags: cakephp

Let's assume I 've a table and want to select the first 10 rows from
 that table but I want to be sure that no other scripts will select the
 same rows I've previously got by the first script.

How can I do that?

my table contains one primary key. Let's say id is the column name.
 So my first script is running and select the ids: 1, 2, 3 .... 10

Then that script will play with the returned ids.
In the same time, I'm running a second script and do the same select.
 But I don't want him to get the first 10 ids.

How can i lock the row table in cakephp ?
please help me thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = 0
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE .... LIMIT $number, 10"
$number += 10
```

Answer (score 0):

its more for read locking but im sure you can get some ideas here https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/tree/beta/core/locks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible without using native SQL (SELECT FOR UPDATE). There is an interesting thread here

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cake-php/WCvWGsTTRjw